# Can Quartz.NET (2.x) with SQL Persistence Be Used Across Multiple Servers

Tags: quartz.net

I'm new to Quartz.net, and am currently using the 2.x version - I'm just trying to work out if its possible to use the quartz scheduler across multiple servers, all pointing at the same database.

My main motivation for this is for a fail-over mechanism, but also to spread the load.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is built-in functionality. See Clustering in tutorial: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/tutorial/lesson_11.html